# Bash: How to add character at the end of a line if it doesn't exist?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Suppose I had the following text in a csv file:

```
454,'steve',3434
123,'john',3454,
2343,'mike',5757
```

What I would like to do is to insert a new column at the end of each line. However, as seen in the example above, not all lines have a comma at the end of it.

The end result should be

```
454,'steve',3434,'2018-10-12'
123,'john',3454,'2018-10-12'
2343,'mike',5757,'2018-10-12'
```

How can one achieve this using bash?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed "s/,\{0,1\}$/,'2018-10-12'/" file
```

```
454,'steve',3434,'2018-10-12'
123,'john',3454,'2018-10-12'
2343,'mike',5757,'2018-10-12'
```

Regex pattern `,*$` matches 0 or more commas in the end and replaces with the given string.

Comment: Seems a bit fragile, as it will misbehave on a line with an empty 3rd column, like `123,'foo',,`.  Probably safer to do something like `sed -e 's/,//3' -e "s/\$/,'2018-10-12'/"`

Comment: Good point @WilliamPursell, I have addresses this with `sed "s/,\{0,1\}$/,'2018-10-12'/" file`

Answer (score 3):

`awk` will take care of it.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v d="'2018-10-12'" '{$4=d}1' file

454,'steve',3434,'2018-10-12'
123,'john',3454,'2018-10-12'
2343,'mike',5757,'2018-10-12'
```

since we know the date is non-empty, you can golf it to

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v d="'2018-10-12'" '$4=d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming csv fields do not contain commas, how about:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, -v q=\' '{$NF==""? p=NF: p=NF+1; $p=q"2018-10-12"q; print}' file.csv
```

It does not require to hard-code the column numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Perl`

First, replace all the ',\n' with '\n' and then replace all '\n' with ',\n'.

```
perl -pe 's/,\n/\n/g' file.txt | perl -pe 's/\n/, 2018-10-12\n/g'
```

> 454,'steve',3434, 2018-10-12
>
> 123,'john',3454, 2018-10-12
>
> 2343,'mike',5757, 2018-10-12

Comment: In the OP, under "The end result should be" it shows each line directly under the next without a blank line in between as you answer does! Also, you are needlessly piping the output of the first perl command to another perl command when as in the answer by stack0114106 it is simple and direct: `perl -pe " s/(,)?$/,'2018-10-12'/ " file`

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
 perl -pe " s/(,)?$/,'2018-10-12'/ "
```

with Inputs:

```
$ cat pollpenn.txt
454,'steve',3434
123,'john',3454,
2343,'mike',5757
$  perl -pe " s/(,)?$/,'2018-10-12'/ " pollpenn.txt
454,'steve',3434,'2018-10-12'
123,'john',3454,'2018-10-12'
2343,'mike',5757,'2018-10-12'
$
```